# Xcode 5.0.2 and iOS 7.0.4 Deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I'm trying to deploy an iOS App to my iPhone 5 running iOS 7.0.4 with Xcode 5.0.2. I don't have an Apple Developer Account so i followed all the steps in this tutorial:

[tutorial ios and xcode without dev account](http://mhassan.me/2013/02/15/using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/)

My iPhone is jailbroken, Appsync is installed and Xcode installs the App successfully. I can run it on the phone but I can't debug it. What are the right steps for this Xcode/iOS combination?

Best Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok people, got it! :-)

Debugging is now working properly.

Just follow the steps in this tutorial. The binary patching isn't needed.

[xcode 5.0.2, ios 7.0.4 app deployment WITHOUT paid developer account](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/)

Best Regards
Stefan